# C Recursive Directory copy of sub folders

Tags: c, recursion, copy

I'm having issues getting the following code to run to recursively copy sub-folders in C. I saw this in another post but the code seem to not run the if statement to check if the current file is a directory.

```
void SearchDirectory(const char *name) {
DIR *dir = opendir(name);                
if(dir) {
    char Path[256], *EndPtr = Path;
    struct dirent *e;
    strcpy(Path, name);                  
    EndPtr += strlen(name);              
    while((e = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {  
        struct stat info;                
        strcpy(EndPtr, e->d_name);       
        if(!stat(Path, &info)) {         //code stops here and won't check if the current file is a directory or not..
            if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) {  

                SearchDirectory(Path);   
            } else if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode) { 
                //Copy routine
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

*Edit*

So I added a slash on the the end of the path and it seem to find the directory but is crashing with stack error on execution. I think it is recursing without end. New code is:

```
void SearchDirectory(const char *name) {
DIR *dir = opendir(name);                
if(dir) {
    char Path[256], *EndPtr = Path;
    struct dirent *e;
    strcpy(Path, name);   
strcat(Path, slash);               
    EndPtr += (strlen(name)+1);              
    while((e = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {  
        struct stat info;                
        strcpy(EndPtr, e->d_name);       
        if(!stat(Path, &info)) {         //code stops here and won't check if the current file is a directory or not..
            if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) {  

                SearchDirectory(Path);   
            } else if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode) { 
                //Copy routine
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a nice oppertunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's failing to insert the directory separator character (`/`) between the base directory and the appended part.

Assuming `name = "/home/foo/bar"`, `EndPtr` will point at the `'\0'` at the end, and then `e->d_name` is copied there, without anything in-between. This is wrong, it will create a mashed-up filename.

Comment: so do I need to strcat a / between the Path and name?

Comment: Still not working, I've tried a few things and most of them end in a stack crash because it is calling with recursion infinitely I think. I thought I has a good termination check, if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) but it doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

I could not test your code myself, I do not have the right libraries installed., but 
there is an example that may be helpful ***[here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fo%2Fopendir.html)*** of using opendir et. al.